# Preserving (reconstructing?) single quotes in Bash arguments to script commands

Tags: bash, grep, quotes

I wrote a shell script that lets me grep through a directory tree and preserve the path in the grep output. 
It started out like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# findjs.sh
# Given a word or argument, greps javascript files from one dir down to the 8th dir down,
# as in: */*.js */*/*.js ... */*/*/*/*/*/*.js 

f="*/*.js"
for p in {1..8}
do
    echo 'Searching '"$f"
    grep -in $1 $f;
    f="*/"$f
done
```

Works quite well. Problem is if I want to send a multi word string as my search term it expands them. This is OK:

```
./findjs.sh  aword /var/local/somedir
```

This is not:

```
./findjs.sh  'the message' /var/local/somedir
```

Bash devolves the grep line to

```
grep -in the message /var/local/somedir
```

I have tried all kinds of things to try and wrap $1 in single quotes
like this:

```
escaped="'\''"
t=$escaped$1$escaped
```

or

```
grep -in $escaped$1$escaped $fp;
```

and single quotes in double quotes, etc etc. but single quotes disappear every time.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
grep "$1" ...
```

... should work just fine

Comment: And so it does. Missed the obvious, obviously.